# What is the bug in the MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, debugging

I have the MySQL `INSERT ROW` below. For some reason I keep getting a syntax error with this. Any ideas? I have checked my table multiple times to make sure those table columns exist.

`INSERT INTO content_pieces (content_id, order, piece, type) VALUES ('$content_id', '$key', '$indiv_piece', '$piece_attr')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`order` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mySQL.

You need to wrap it in backticks:

```
(`content_id`, `order`, `piece`, `type`)
```

or - better -  use a different column name.

Answer (score 1):

Backtick your column values `order` is a reserved SQL keyword.